# Falla de validación?

Tags: mysql, laravel

Estoy realizando un buscador a través de un modal, en algunas pruebas que he estado haciendo ha funcionado correctamente, trae la información si el estado es `N`, y sale una alerta si es `S`.

Bueno, pero en una de esas pruebas me di cuenta que salia error, debido a una linea de código que he puesto en donde a fuerza tiene que encontrar algo en la tabla unida(Inner join) para validar el siguiente `if`. Pero ¿qué pasa si no existe un dato que le mando a través del buscador? ¿Cómo puedo controlar para que no me marque error?

Este es el código del html en blade ya que trabajo en Laravel:

```
    @include('emails.partials.footer')

    @if ($query != "")
        @if ($alumno[0]->pagado == 'S')
            <script>
                alert("Este alumno no tiene pagos pendientes");
            </script>
            <tfoot>
            <th> TOTAL</th>
            <th>
                <h4 id="total"> $/. 0.0</h4>
                <input type="hidden" name="total_venta" id="total_venta">
            </th>
            </tfoot>
            <tbody>
            </tbody>
        @else
            @foreach ($alumno as $alum)
                <tfoot>
                <th> TOTAL</th>
                <th>
                    <h4 id="totalC"> $/. {{ $alum->cantidadProgramada }}</h4>
                    <input type="hidden" name="total_venta" id="total_venta">
                </th>
                </tfoot>
                <tbody>
                <tr id="fila">
                    <th id="idAlumnosCxC">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning"
                                onclick="eliminar({{$alum->idAlumnosCxC}})">
                            X
                        </button>
                    </th>
                    <th id="nombre">{{$alum->nombre}}</th>
                    <th id="ciclo">{{$alum->descripcion}}</th>
                    <th id="plan">{{$alum->codigoPlan}}</th>
                    <th id="clave">{{$alum->clave}}</th>
                    <th id="cantidadProgramada">
                        {{$alum->cantidadProgramada}}
                    </th>
                </tr>
                </tbody>
            @endforeach
        @endif
    @else
        <tfoot>
        <th> TOTAL</th>
        <th>
            <h4 id="total"> $/. 0.0</h4>
            <input type="hidden" name="total_venta" id="total_venta">
        </th>
        </tfoot>
    @endif
```

y el controlador:

```
public function create(Request $request)
{

    if ($request)
    {
        $query = trim($request->get('searchText'));

        $alumno = DB::table('alumno as a')
            ->join('alumnocxc as acxc', 'a.idAlumno', '=', 'acxc.idAlumno')
            ->join('ciclo as c', 'acxc.idCiclo', '=', 'c.idCiclo')
            ->join('planespago as pp', 'acxc.idPlan', '=', 'pp.idPlanesPago')
            ->select('acxc.idAlumnosCxC',
                DB::raw('concat(a.nombre," " , a.paterno, " ", a.materno) as nombre'),
                'a.status', 'a.idAlumno', 'acxc.cantidadProgramada', 'acxc.pagado',
                'acxc.cantidadPagada', 'c.descripcion', 'c.idCiclo', 'pp.idPlanesPago',
                'acxc.clave', 'pp.codigoPlan',
                DB::raw('concat(pp.fechaInicio, " " , "a", " " , pp.fechaFin) as fechasPago'),
                'pp.cantidad as totalPagar')
            ->where('a.nombre', 'LIKE', '%' . $query . '%')
            ->orwhere('a.paterno', 'LIKE', '%' . $query . '%')
            ->orwhere('a.materno', 'LIKE', '%' . $query . '%')
            ->orderBy('acxc.idAlumnosCxC', 'desc')
            ->get();
    }

    $folio = DB::table('alumnopagosdet')
        ->select(DB::raw('MAX(reciboCaja) + 1 as folio'))
        ->get();

    $alumnos = DB::table('alumno')
        ->select(DB::raw('CONCAT("No. Alumno: " , idAlumno , " - ", paterno,
         " ", materno, " ", nombre ) as nombre'), 'idAlumno')
        ->where('status', '=', 'A')
        ->get();

    $ciclos = DB::table('ciclo')
        ->select('idCiclo', 'fechaFinal', 'codigoCorto')
        ->orderBy('idCiclo', 'desc')
        ->limit(1)
        ->get();

    $plan = DB::table('planespago')
        ->select('idPlanesPago', 'codigoPlan', 'cantidad',
            DB::raw('CONCAT(fechaInicio, " ", "a", " " , fechaFin) as fechasPago'))
        ->orderBy('idPlanesPago', 'desc')
        ->limit(1)
        ->get();

    return view("utp.venta.planes.create",
        ["alumnos" => $alumnos, "plan" => $plan, "ciclos" => $ciclos,
         "alumno"  => $alumno, "query" => $query, "folio" => $folio]);

}
```

Entiendo que esta linea  **@if($query!="")** indica si es diferente a nulo debería pasar al **else** de ese **if**. Pero no pasa eso e intenta validar la siguiente linea  **@if($alumno[0]->pagado=='S')** en donde ahí se presenta el error. Agradezco cualquier aportación que tengan

Comment: Un consejo Juan, deberías hacer las consultas al estilo Laravel, utilizando [Eloquent](https://laravel.com/docs/eloquent) en vez de utilizar [Query Builder](https://laravel.com/docs/queries), de ese modo las consultas son ḿucho más sencillas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primero

> @if($alumno[0]->pagado=='S')

En esa linea estas comprobado el valor de pagado sobre un array en la posicion 0,
pero puede que la query no te arroje nigun resultado, por ende no existiria ningun array, lo que tienes que hacer es comprobar si existe alumno asi

```
@if($alumno && count($alumno)>0)
```

Y ya despues

```
@if($alumno[0]->pagado=='S')
```